# What is the functionality of __syncTransactions table in SQL Compact database

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

Does anyone know what __syncTransactions table is used for? Here's my scenario:

We have few clients running on SQL Server Compact database syncing with SQL Server 2008 Express server database using Sync Framework v3.5 for a about a year now. It seems that for tables with large number of records (i.e. > 20000), it roughly takes more than a minute to sync and CPU reaches 100% as well.

After enabling sync trace logging, I managed to narrow down the query that was behind the slow syncing. Following is the query that checks for inserts in the client database for one of the tables that contains ~70,000 records:

select 
    ut.* 
from
(
    select 
        ut0.* 
    from 
        [tblPermissionGroupResourceRole] as ut0 
    where
    (       ut0._*sysTrackingContext <> 'a4e40127-4083-4b27-88d0-ef3aed4ae343' 
        OR 
            ut0.*_sysTrackingContext IS NULL
    )
    AND (ut0._*sysChangeTxBsn >= 9486853)

    **AND (ut0.***_sysInsertTxBsn NOT IN (SELECT SyncBsn FROM __syncTransactions))

) as ut 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    select 
        txcs0.* 
    from 
        _*sysTxCommitSequence as txcs0
) as txcs  ON (ut.*_sysInsertTxBsn = txcs._*sysTxBsn) 
WHERE

    COALESCE(txcs.*_sysTxCsn, ut._*sysInsertTxBsn) > 9486853 
AND 
    COALESCE(txcs.*_sysTxCsn, ut.__sysInsertTxBsn) <= 9487480

I have highlighted line that takes roughly 1 minute to execute. The reason is that __syncTransaction table contains around 1200 records and due to the cross reference with 70,000 odd records in my tblPermissionGroupResourceRole table, the query is quite slow.

Therefore, I need to understand how __syncTransactions table is used so I can try and clear records from this table or whether there's any other way to sort out my problem?

Any help is much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Sasanka.